# Uniqueness of Iteratively Reweighted Least Squares

Tags: statistics, reference-request, least-squares

This is a more general question.  Suppose I have a heteroscedastic data set that I'd like to fit using IRLS (iteratively re-weighted least squares) to determine $a,b,c,d$.  E.g.

$f_{model}(x) \approx a + b\, x + \epsilon(x)$,

where I assume $\epsilon(x) \sim N(0,c+d \, x)$.

We are given experimental data $f_{exp,j}(x_i)$ obtained at some set of $x_i, \; i = 1,...,n$, $j = 1,...,m$.  Assume the objective function is sum of square error.

IRLS seems like a reasonable method for determining $a,b,c,d$.  However, while ordinary least squares is guaranteed to have a unique solution under certain conditions, I have seen no such guarantee for IRLS, nor is one likely given the non-linear nature of the algorithm.  Does anyone know under what conditions IRLS yields a unique solution?  What if x is multi-variate?  Perhaps it's convergent in the limit of $m \to \infty$ (large number of data points)?

Comment: What is the objective that you're minimizing?  The sum of absolute deviations is most commonly used, but IRLS can be used for other loss function.  For the sum of absolute deviations case, there are many examples where the solution is non-unique.

Comment: Sorry, I will add that.  I was thinking sum of square error.  If it's not unique, I am a little concerned IRLS isn't really all that useful (admittedly a subjective response).

Comment: In your updated description, the problem is an ordinary  linear least squares problem for which IRLS makes no sense.

Comment: I'll remove the formula.  I don't want to list the specific weighting here, keep it general.

Comment: Also Brian, I am actually located in town.  Perhaps I will contact you next week to discuss?  It's work related, not a toy problem.